# How to delete chat comments?

Tags: support, chat

A questioner has sufficiently clarified his question that my comments are no longer valid.  Normally, I'd just delete them, but they've been moved to chat, and I don't see a way to remove them.

Thanks

Comment: When something goes to the chat room it is as good as deleted anyway. Why bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat messages can't be removed after the edit period of 2 minutes. They will stay in the chat the way they are. Mods can theoretically change them, but there is no reason why they would need to do that for comments that served their purpose and were moved to chat.

See also: 
[Why is there a timeout to delete your own chat messages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263853/352819) and 
[Allow owner of message to delete them in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80085/352819)

Comment: There's also the possibility to flag chat messages and request deletion, but I'd expect that unless you are able to make a very good case for it, deletion won't happen. I very, very strongly doubt that they will be deleted just because "they have served their purpose"; that's not how chat works. (Incidentally, this is also one reason why I *don't* always just move to chat; sometimes, people might legitimately intend for their comments to be strictly ephemeral, and moving to chat changes that by the whim of someone else.)